# How to have panels constant throughout the application

Tags: css, html

I have a page where I have three panels...left panel,center panel,right panel...My question is this...I have a link in my center panel and that link takes to another page...But I want the new page to be displayed in the center panel with the condition that left and right panel should remain as such...I am able to display the 2nd page in center panel but I am not able to hold back the left and right panel...

My code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="centerPanel">
       center panel
       <a href="<s:url action="ViewAppeals"/>">View Appeals</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="leftPanel">
   leftpanel
</div>

<div id="rightPanel">
   rightpanel
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the left and right panels to stay static while updating the center panel? If so, you should use ajax or `iframe`.

Comment: Is there any way of doing that with div

Comment: no. Without `<iframe/>` or ajax the nearest you come would be positioning the left and right panel fixed. If the browser renders fast it may look like you just updated the content div, but it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it, although it may not be what you're looking for.

I made a div for each page like so for the content:

```
<div id="pagewrap" style="">
    <!---------------Home Page--------------->
    <div id="Content1"> 
        <object id="dHome" data="home.html" style="overflow:hidden;margin:5px;">
        </object>
    </div>
    <!----------------Gallery Page--------------->
    <div id="Content2"> 
        <object id="dGallery" data="gallery.html"> 
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on...

As you can see above, I used objects as my pages to load external html data.

I set the width of the wrapper - `pagewrap` to the sum of the widths of all the pages, and used Jquery to move the pages to the left or right, depending which button was clicked.

Here is the code when paging to the right:

```
$('#pagewrap').animate({'marginLeft' : "-=650px"},200);
```

and left:

```
$('#pagewrap').animate({'marginLeft' : "+=650px"},200);
```

The above `650px` is the with of all my content pages.

> **Or you could just change the source file of the object!**

*Hope this helps*

Comment: `<object/>` and `<embed/>` for loading html content? I would recommend `<iframe/>`.

Comment: That would be easier, I agree.